# React FormData not giving image

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-dom, react-forms

I'm trying to get image using `FormData`
`const data = new FormData(event.target);` but when I do `data.get("image")` I get null , I've set up loading the image in other component and I'm successful in showing the image on screen

in `Auth.js`   `{!isLogin && <ImageUpload id="image"/>}`

in `ImageUpload`

````js
<div>
  <input className="form-control" id={props.id} onChange={pickedHandler} type="file" style={{display:"none"}} accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg" ref={filePickerRef}/>
            
<div className="container mx-auto d-flex justify-content-center">

{previewUrl && <img id="image" name="image" className="mb-3 mt-4" src={previewUrl} alt="preview"/>}
{!previewUrl && <p> select a image </p>}

  </div>
 <button className="form-control btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick={pickImageHandler}>pick image</button>
        </div>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add

`name="image"`
in input tag

```js
 <input name="image" className="form-control" id={props.id} onChange={pickedHandler} type="file" style={{display:"none"}} accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg" ref={filePickerRef}/>
```